# Regex to remove character from within a string after alphabetic characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string of characters, 
`String a = "abcd000324";`

I would like to remove the 0's from the string using a regex to result in the string `abcd324`

Is there a regex value to replace a certain character (i.e. 0) after alphabetic characters but not remove the 324. It would also need to work in the case of the number appearing later in the string, i.e. `abcd0034505` should result to `abcd34505`

Comment: "after alphanumeric characters"... Do really mean "After alphabetical characters"?

Comment: What should be done in the following case: `abcd05050505`?

Comment: that would result in abcd5050505, I would only like to remove the integer value after the alphabetic value until another value appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo can search using this regex:

```
^(\D*)0+
```

And replace it by using `"$1"` which is back-reference of first group which is `\D*` i.e. 0 or more non-digit characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KXWeOg/1)

Java code:

```
String repl = input.replaceFirst("^(\D*)0+", "$1");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for also explaining your regex.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to replace parts of the regex back into itself, use positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`):

```
(?<=\D)0+
```

This will match a sequence of zeros *only* if they are preceded by some non-digit character. You can now do

```
str.replaceFirst("(?<=\\D)0+", "")
```

without having to pass any references to capture groups.

[Link to Regex101 example.](https://regex101.com/r/KXWeOg/3)

Comment: `(?<=\D+)` makes it a variable length lookbehind, not allowed in Java and many other regex flavors.

Comment: @anubhava. Thanks for the catch. A single-character match is all that is required, so fixed.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry for shamelessly incorporating all the elements of your answer into mine after I wrote it, like the regex example and using `replaceFirst`.

Comment: It is absolutely fine as you have different approach in regex used.

Comment: I was hoping you would see it that way too :)

Comment: I also like this approach since I do not have to replace the removal with the piece I removed